# SQL AVG() function returns INT when multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

EDIT: I did a mistake writing `WHERE Users.Username=?` instead of `WHERE Answers.Username=?`

---

If I use the following statement I get correct average 3.33:

```
public final String SELECT_USER_AND_AVGANSWERS_STMT =
"SELECT AVG(CAST(Answers.Rating AS FLOAT)) FROM Answers "
+ "WHERE Answers.Username=?";
```

Notice I am only selecting AVG. When I try select more columns it returns 4, as in it rounded it up.

```
public final String SELECT_USER_AND_AVGANSWERS_STMT = 
"SELECT Users.Username, Users.Nickname, AVG(CAST(Answers.Rating AS FLOAT)) "
+ "FROM Users, Answers "
+ "WHERE Users.Username=?"
+ "GROUP BY Users.Username, Users.Nickname";
```

Users Table:

```
"CREATE TABLE Users(Username VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,"
+ "Password VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,"
+ "Nickname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
+ "Description VARCHAR(50),"
+ "Photo VARCHAR(4000))";
```

Answers Table:

```
"CREATE TABLE Answers(AnswerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,"
+ "QuestionID INTEGER NOT NULL,"
+ "SubmittedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"
+ "Text VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,"
+ "Username VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,"
+ "Rating INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)";
```

Using Java / Embedded Derby database.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, you are trying to match the `Users.Username` in this query, but `Answers.Username` in your first query, so this is one problem! This should work:

```
SELECT Users.Username, Users.Nickname, AVG(CAST(Answers.Rating AS FLOAT))
FROM Users, Answers
WHERE Answers.Username=?
GROUP BY Users.Username, Users.Nickname
```

Something else that could be problematic is whether or not the aggregation happens before the `CAST`. To check this you could use:

```
SELECT UserName, NickName, CAST(AVG(AnswersRating) AS FLOAT)
FROM
(
    SELECT Users.Username As UserName, Users.Nickname As NickName, CAST(Answers.Rating AS FLOAT) As AnswersRating
    FROM Users, Answers
    WHERE Answers.Username=?
) AS Float_Table
GROUP BY UserName, NickName
```

Comment: Try the new solution?

Comment: nope, i tried all the possibilities of putting CAST and still doesn't work, looking at your solution you would think it would work though, still wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you do `SELECT * FROM Users, Answers WHERE Users.Username = ?` and put the results in the question?

Comment: im trying to understand how to view the results from eclipse. Since i was writing these in a servlet. Any idea how i can view the results?

Comment: Looked at a youtube video, will post results in a few minutes.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for the hassle, My problem was that I did "WHERE Users.Username=?" instead of "WHERE Answers.Username=?"

Comment: I would really like to thank you though for making me look into how to view SQL statements, now i can run them and see results right away instead of trying to do lots of java code to see what the results are. thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104777/discussion-between-jcollerton-and-imzyzzbrah).

Comment: Just make the answer something like "You did the WHERE statement on the wrong column" and change it to my original query but with where on Answers.Username